# How to determine if a JCR property is multivalue?

Tags: aem, jcr

How do you determine if a JCR property is multivalve?  I tried calling getType() on the property but that returns the same value if it's a String or String Array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `isMultiple()` method of the [Property](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Property.html) class you can determine if the property is multi-valued or not.

```
Property prop = node.getProperty("some-property");
if (prop.isMultiple()) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```